# Complex Potential

Tags: complex-analysis, fluid-dynamics

An incompressible inviscid fluid fills a long circular cylinder of radius a. Show that if there is a line vortex of circulation $2\pi \Gamma$ parallel to the axis of the cylinder and at a distance $b (< a)$ from it, it will revolve around the axis with a constant speed $(\Gamma b)/(a^2−b^2)$.

So i know that we have a vortex and the complex potential is
$-(i\Gamma/2\pi)*\ln(z)$

since we are given speed that is $w'(z)$, right? so how would we go about showing all this. where would we start? would we start by integrating $w'(z)$? or could we start with a vortex pair within the cylinder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orient the coordinate system so that the vortex inside the cylinder is at the point $z_b =b +i\cdot 0$ on the real axis.  To satisfy the no flux condition at the surface of the cylinder the velocity field inside the cylinder can be obtained using the **method of images** with another vortex of equal and opposite strength placed at the point $z_c =c + i \cdot 0$ where $bc = a^2$.

There is no self-induced motion of the vortex at $z_b$.  The motion of this vortex is due to the velocity field produced by the image vortex alone with potential

$$f_c(z) = \frac{i2 \pi\Gamma}{2\pi}\log (z - z_c),$$

and complex velocity

$$u-iv =-\frac{d f_c}{dz} = -i \Gamma \frac{1}{z - z_c}$$

The velocity at the location $z_b$ is

$$u(z_b) - i v(z_b) = -i \Gamma \frac{1}{z_b - z_c} = i\frac{\Gamma}{c - b} = i\frac{\Gamma b}{bc - b^2} = i \frac{\Gamma b}{a^2- b^2}$$

Hence the vortex at $z_b$ moves with speed given by the modulus

$$|u(z_b) - i v(z_b)| = \frac{\Gamma b}{a^2 - b^2}$$

Comment: At this instant of time we have $u = 0$ and $v \neq 0$ so the direction of motion is normal to the real axis.  The ultimate path is in a circle around the centerline.